# Solr query failing - q=(name:abc OR name:def) AND (desc:aaa OR desc:bbb)

Tags: solr

Can someone please tell me why is the following query does not return any results :

q=(name:abc OR name:def) AND (desc:aaa OR desc:bbb)

Thanks.

Comment: What is in your Solr index? Do you commit it before run your query?

Comment: I am using Lucene index.

Comment: What does `q=*:*` return?

Comment: q=*:* does not return any records.

Comment: Can someone guide me to some similar examples of what I am trying to do q=(name:abc OR name:def) AND (desc:aaa OR desc:bbb)